# I need this number pyramid to print out a specific sequence of numbers to the console?

Tags: c++

I need a Number pyramid identical to this one:

```
     1
    121
   12321
  1234321
 123454321
12345654321
```

I am new to programming and if anyone would't mine running through the code and telling me how each line is being understood by the compiler.

I heard there was a way to do this with embedded while loops. If anyone knows how to do that and can show me, that would be great.

The code I have is partially from the internet and not solely mine.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
{
    for (int space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space)
    {
        cout << "  ";
        ++count;
    }

    while (k != 2 * i - 1)
    {
        if (count <= rows - 1)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
            ++count;
        }
        else
        {
            ++count1;
            cout << i + k - 2 * count1 << " ";
        }
        ++k;
    }
    count1 = count = k = 0;
    cout << endl;
}

cout << "\n\n\n";
system("PAUSE");
```

Comment: *"... anyone would't mine running through the code and telling me how each line is being understood by the compiler. "* - That's not a useful question. *"If anyone knows how to do that and can show me, that would be great"* - Neither is this. I suggest you rethink your strategy. You should do your own work, and ask specific questions when you have them.

Comment: Don't even think about code for now. Pull out a pencil and some paper and figure out how you the person would write the pyramid out. take good notes and that's the beginning of your design. Code comes from the design. If you code without a plan you're going to have to get used to writing and rewriting and rewriting until you get it right by trial and error.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: "if anyone would't mine running through the code and telling me how each line is being understood by the compiler" There are programs that do almost exactly that, called debuggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
int main(void) {
  int i, j, k, l, n = 6;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
      cout << " ";
    }
    for (k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
      cout << k;
    }
    for (l = i - 1; l >= 1; l--) {
      cout << l;
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 But, we here to help and I think that code doesn't have much to understand, if anyone has some knowledge about coding like if-else, for loop that can able to understand easily. And if you find any issue or want some changes in question then you are most welcome to edit it.